# Как сделать функцию для поиска критических значений Фишера в js?

Tags: javascript, статистика, теория-вероятностей

Как сделать функцию для поиска критических значений Фишера в js по типу как она реализована в Excele FРАСПОБР? Или хотя-бы библиотека в которой уже есть этот функционал. Критические значения Фишера должны совпадать с таблицей критических значений Фишера.[image: Таблица критический значений критерия Фишера при уровне значимости 0.05]

Comment: Есть вариант пойти напролом, и сделать двумерный массив, в который забить эту табличку, и подавать значения k1 и k2 вручную. А потом просто сделать вывод элемента, который соответствует k1 и k2.

Comment: Проблема в том что значения k1 и k2 будут больше чем в этой таблице (до 100) и поэтому есть потребность в программном рассчитывании.